# PHP refer to a file without DOCUMENT_ROOT

Tags: php

So my problem is, that if I include a php file, the main php will be the path. I can't describe it well, so let me show you some easy-to-understand code:

**This is my site:**

> localhost/mysite/index.php

```
<?php
    include('common/sayHello.php');
?>
```

**And I have an admin folder**

> localhost/mysite/admin/index.php

**And I've got some common files**

> localhost/mysite/common/sayHello.php

```
<?php
    $text = file_get_contents(helloText.txt);
    echo($text);
?>
```

> localhost/mysite/common/helloText.txt

```
Hey! How you doing?
```

But it doesn't work. The main "mysite/index.php" will look for "mysite/helloText.txt", and the "mysite/admin/index.php" will look for "mysite/admin/helloText.txt".

Can I refer correctly to the helloText file, without using DOCUMENT_ROOT? Is there a way to include files without changing the url path?

You may say, that I should use a "/" before "common/helloText.txt", but then it will look for localhost/common/helloText.txt instead of localhost/mysite/...

Comment: So use `/mysite/common/helloText.txt`.

Comment: If you don't want to hard-code the full path, why don't you want to use `DOCUMENT_ROOT`? This is precisely what it's for.

Comment: @Barmar but I would like to use it on the web too.. so if I upload the final version (mysite.com/) then it would look for (mysite.com/mysite/common..)..

Comment: Why wouldn't `DOCUMENT_ROOT` work for that?

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose I usually define two constants in my config:

```
define('PATH_ROOT', '/var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/');
define('HTTP_ROOT', 'http://example.com/');
```

So now I can easily define absolute paths within the application with `PATH_ROOT`, and within the website with `HTTP_ROOT`.

So then we have something like:

```
$myFile = 'some/path/foo.txt';
// write file to: /var/www/vhosts/example.com/app/some/path/foo.txt
file_put_contents('Hello world!', PATH_ROOT . $myFile);
// generate link to: http://example.com/some/path/foo.txt
sprintf('<a href="%s">Click me!</a>', HTTP_ROOT . $myFile);
```

And if your application moves all you need to do is modify those two constants.